# Changing Java Version From Within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, version

I wrote a project in eclipse with an older version of java.
Now on a different computer but running the same codes I'm getting a whole lot of red.

This is due to Version incompatibility.
I've had my professor change the Java version from within the console window before. The code compiled just fine after he did so. I'm sure its the same case with this code.

After looking at other tutorials and google links I could only find command line approaches and @override methods. To be honest I still don't understand these.

What is the best way to change the version of a code originally written in an older code inside the eclipse console?
thanks!

Answer (score 30):

In eclipse go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler`, there you can change the java versions. Hope it helps.

Comment: That changes what compiler(s) are available. To change the settings of the Java level to check for the project, in the Package/Project Explorer, right click on the Project, select Properties and then select Java Compiler.

Comment: awesome! that looks like the right approach, but when I change it to version 1.6 (from 1.7 as displayed in the original properties of the project) (EDIT: the 1.7 is not supported on my computer) the majority of the code did not become compatible. in the import statements the "java.awt" is still being underlined so I know its not a coding issue.
Is going from 1.7 to 1.6 impossible?
I tried to get them all to run the same version but i keep getting the same problem.

Comment: correction: I'll update the project to 1.6 but when I go back to the properties it'll say 1.7 again. :/

Answer (score 23):

Ideally if we want to have two different versions of Java [say 1.6 and 1.7], then we should have two workspace defined accordingly to avoid any mixup. We can also change the Project Facets if our projects has facets that is.

In Eclipse Follow steps given below: 
1) Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler and as per the image set the compliance compiler level as per your requirements.
[image: Compiler Compliance Level Not Project Specific]

2) Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's and check if your required jre/jdk is available or not as given in image below: 
[image: Installed JRE's Not Project Specific]

3) Right Click on Your Project and go to Java Build Path and check if your required Library is available or not as per image given below:
[image: Java Build Path Project Specific]

4) Now you can edit the JRE System Library or add one by clicking on button's available on last image's right side, then a pop up as given below will open up. Here, you can change the execution environment [default values also can be set]
[image: Edit/Add Library]

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed. It might also help to change the JVM Eclipse uses to the one you're upgrading to via the `eclipse.ini` file. You can check which JVM your Eclipse is using via "Help -> Installation Details -> Configuration" and looking for the `-vm` line.

Answer (score 1):

In myeclipse select the project -> properties -> java compiler -> there you can specify jdk version.

Comment: Also works for standard Eclipse, it's setting the requirements for the project as opposed to the available compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Easy

1. Download the jdk from Oracle's official website for the version you want to compile your project with.

[JDK Oracle's official](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/archive/)

2. create a new Java project

[[image]

3. Once the project has been generated, If you select the part that says *Configure JREs*

[image]

4. By default eclipse will use the version you have installed on your system so if you don't change this configuration you will never be able to run the program with the build you need, in this case I will use jdk 1.8.
5. After pressing **Add**

[image]

5.1 And choose the option select the 3rd option in this case, called **Standard VM** and press **Next**

[image]

6. Now eclipse asks us to indicate the path where the libraries and other content is located in order to compile and run the program, we only have to indicate the directory where it is located.

[image]

7. As my goal is to run a program with the JRE 8 , I will look for the directory path where the download described in option 1 of this message is located.

[image]

8. As a quick example, since I just want my program to compile without worrying about anything else, I will add all the contents of my address.

[image]

9. Now we change by clicking on the JRE we want to compile our program, to be changed to the original default so that the new selection is executed ; and finally we press **Apply and Close** and **Next**

[image]

10. Press **Finish** to create the project

[image]

11. Now we have the whole project with all the necessary content to compile and run it.

[image]

Personally I think this is the quickest and cleanest way to do it ; the problem I encountered when I changed JDK is that when compiling I couldn't find the directory with the necessary components to run it, you had to download it and configure it together with the default parameters, which can cause a lot of headaches for less experienced users.

Finally, this is the version of eclipse that I am using

[image]

I hope you find this system useful, I use it to be able to run old examples that use **applets** , which are obsolete classes and jvm does not compile.