# Accidentally changed Eclipse JRE

Tags: eclipse

I accidentally clicked an intellisense tip to change my Eclipse settings to jre 1.4 and it messed up my whole project! How can I undo this? I searched online for an answer but couldn't find anything.

Thank you!

Comment: What, really? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424528/changing-java-version-from-within-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Mac OS X then follow as follow. [(ScreenShot)](https://blog.gaurangjadia.com/?attachment_id=838)

```
Preferences
    |
    -> Java
        |
        -> Installed JREs
           (You can add or update existing paths to JRE in your system.)
```