# I unintentionally changed my JRE in Eclipse - how can I get it back?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my efforts to figure how to exercise various features of the Android system, I have downloaded several sample codes and run them on my phone.  One of those that I downloaded would not compile.  The autofix gave me an option that I believe to have changed my build path.  The fix worked but it can with a painful side-effect:  Now none of my other sample codes compile.

I followed the instructions in [Accidentally changed Eclipse JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203224/accidentally-changed-eclipse-jre) and added the only JRE that Eclipse seems to have found on my computer 
(JRE System Library [Java SE 6 [1.6.0_65-b14-462]] ).  However, I still get compile errors which suggest to me that it is not finding a JRE.   (e.g. public class MainActivity extends Activity - I get "Activity cannot be resolved to a type."

Is there a way to get back to the build path I had an hour ago?

Comment: I have discovered that I can fix each of my other sample codes (aka projects) by going into each one clicking "fix setup" when autofix gives me the option.  But, I remain mystified.

Answer (score 0):

by using Eclipse IDE follow below steps

```
1) right click on project > Go to Properties > Java Compiler > chang compiler version what you want
```

hope it will help you