# Can I install multiple JDK's on OSX?

Tags: java, macos, android-studio

I'm told that for the android app I am trying ot help develop to work, I need to have Java 6, not 7 or 8.  Unfortunately I have 7 installed.

I know that on Linux, multiple copies of the JDK can be installed.  Is this possible with OSX?  Or to at least tell the IDE to use a different JDK?

Comment: Yes. You can install as many different versions of the JDK as you want, and you can pick which one you use.

Comment: Why do you need to have Java 6? Java is backwards compatible, so you can compile to Java 6 from Java 7 or 8, with the `-source` and `-target` flags.

Comment: @kayaman I'm working on a previously developed Android App and would prefer to run everything from the IDE as opposed to from Terminal.  Unless you're implying to add those switches in the Terminal?

Comment: @StuartKuredjian Believe me, IDEs can do everything that the terminal does, so that's not an excuse. Just configure the source and target levels in the IDE.

Comment: @kayaman I'm not sure what your point is.  I already know that. I'm asking how to run the app with Java 6 from the IDE as opposed to the Terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can install different JDK versions on the same machine. In Eclipse you can explicitly specify what version of the JDK to use.


However, I would like to point out that Java is backwards-compatible. There's no need for you to downgrade.

Comment: Thanks Yasmani.  I agree that Java is backwards-compatible and there should be no  need to downgrade.  All the same, I'd like to follow my Project Manager's instructions so he can't come back and say I didn't use Java 6.  For my clarification can you please explain how to import Java 6 into my IDE (I'm using Android Stuido but it's pretty much Eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install. I have java6, 7, and 8 on my mac.

A note, if you are trying to run it from the command line you can just change the Java home using this:

for Java 6

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`
```

for Java 7

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

for Java 8

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

Once they are installed you can just load them on your IDE by setting up the java home to the version you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424528/changing-java-version-from-within-eclipse