# How to correctly select Java SDK in OS X?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I seem to have a bit of a mess. At the terminal, I get:

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

Which is good (I'm trying to get Java 8 running). `which java` gives `/usr/bin/java` and:

```
> ls -al /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Here I think I see where Java is actually installed.

Now my problem is that when I code a simple Java program and type:

```
System.out.println( System.getProperty("java.version") )
System.out.println( System.getProperty("java.vendor") )
```

I get the output:

```
1.6.0_65
Apple Inc.
```

So what am I doing wrong?

p.s. I am using Eclipse and while I can manually select a different JDK to use there, I would like Java 8 to be a system default. For example, I recently downloaded Eclipse Luna which does not open, giving the following error message:

```
Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable with this product.
```

Comment: How do you run the "simple Java program"?

Comment: Well, I am kind of cheating. I have Eclipse for Scala installed and working somehow, so the "simple Java program" was actually a "simple Scala program". However, I am not the only one detecting Java 1.6 installed. When I open Minecraft it also finds Java 1.6.

Comment: So you are running the program from inside eclipse?

Comment: Do you need Java 1.6? Have you tried uninstalling it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the java home using:

/usr/libexec/java_home 
Move to that directory:

cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home

cd bin
java -version

To switch the jdk 8 you will need to modify /usr/libexec/java_home to correctly point to java 8.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately ``/usr/libexec/java_home`` returns the correct version already: ``/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home``. However, Eclipse Luna detects a Java 1.6 (and so does Minecraft, by the way).

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424528/changing-java-version-from-within-eclipse