# Errors in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, parsing

Last week I updated the SDKs and I had some problems, so I downloaded a new version of Eclipse. But then somethings started to happen. 
For example, I had some projects that I picked a double from a EditText using

Double d = Double.parseDouble(v1.getText().toString());

Now, this isn't working anymore. Every time I try to do this, there is a NumberFormatException, but I believe the problem isn't in the conversion, cause I'm doing the exactly same thing I used to do in other projects.
I can't even display datas in TextViews. I'm not sure what's going on here. I'm new to this and I don't undestand too much about Android/Eclipse/Java, but I'm sure that there isn't anything wrong in the project, because I'm doing the same thing that used to work until last week.

Actually, when I saw it wasn't working I tried to download the same version I had, but this errors continued to happen. I guess the problem is in my pc, but I would like to know if it has already happened with anyone.

If someone know what's going on, please answer this! 
Thank you, guys.

Comment: Could it be your Java version? Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424528/changing-java-version-from-within-eclipse - Try to update your Java along with the SDK and change it in your Eclipse.

Comment: Are there any other errors? This will help narrow down the problem. However you should in the meantime right click on the your project in the Package Explorer  then Android Tools> Fix Project Properties. Also clean and rebuild your project after this

Comment: Ihsan, I checked this link you sent and I did everything, but nothing happenned.

Comment: SeahawksRdaBest, yes, there are other errors. For example, I tried to display a data in a TextView, but it didn't display anything. I believe there are other errors that I hadn't seen yet.