# Can I use Eclipse Version Oxygen develop java1.6 web app?

Tags: eclipse

Because My old project is based on java 1.6, Can I use Eclipse  Version Oxygen develop java  1.6  web project ???
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424528/changing-java-version-from-within-eclipse on how to configure them.

Comment: @Jiang - please accept answer and vote up, if my solution has solved your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think `Eclipse` or any `IDE` stops you from importing Java project based on what version of Java you will be using.

For web projects, download Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers.

- https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygenr

You can then configure what version of Java Compiler you would like to use.

- Set Java Compiler : Go to `Windows` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` ->
  `Compiler`
- Add different JRE versions : Go to `Windows` ->
  `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Installed JRE`

[image]

[image]

Here is a sample eclipse documentation for the same.

http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftchangejavalevel.html

Comment: Please accept answer and vote up, if it has helped you solve your problem/question!