# References to interface static methods are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above

Tags: java, eclipse, java-stream

What do I need in order to solve this problem?
How to change JRE Library in Eclipse Project?

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LabelGroup {
SortedSet<String> strSet1 = Stream.of("A", "B", "C", "D")
             .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
    
}
```

Eclipse shows at Stream.of:

References to interface static methods are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above

Tried to install new software from [official site](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/) as suggested [by wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler).

Response:

> Could not find (the software).
>
> About Eclipse: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers Version:
> 2018-12 (4.10.0) Build id: 20181214-0600
>
> Project Settings: java build path: JRE System Library [JavaSE - 1.7]

Comment: Did you make sure that the Java language version for your project is Java10 or above? Java 10 API => `Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet`

Comment: @nullpointer My Project Settings: java build path: JRE System Library [JavaSE - 1.7]

How do I change the Java Language Version?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project

Comment: Your problem is that the exception says that a feature is only available in 1.8 or later and your settings show you are using 1.7.

Comment: Not much value in this Question. Please [search thoroughly](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+do+I+change+the+Java+Language+Version+in+Eclipse&t=osx&ia=web) before posting and do some troubleshooting.

Comment: Duplicate of: [*Changing Java Version From Within Eclipse*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10424528/642706)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Java Version From Within Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424528/changing-java-version-from-within-eclipse)

Comment: I struggled for almost 5 hours to find a solution to my problem.  Tried everything that was suggested in comments. Installed Java 11, changed Build path, changed execution environment ... almost every setting which can show Java 11. But the problem did not solve. Finally when I changed the Compiler Compliance Level to 11, then only the problem got solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have JDK 7 installed instead of JDK 8. The Stream API appeared only in Java 8. You can download Java 8(JDK 8 or OpenJDK) from the official site and install it as a JDK in your project.

---

Click on the **Add Library** button. It brings your [screen](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-add_new_jre.htm) to point to the Java location.

Select **Directory**, button right besides JRE home and point to the installed folder location.

Answer (score 24):

If you're working on a maven project and you're not able to change the JRE Library in Eclipse, then you can add the following dependency to the pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 8):

1)Press on your project with right click and choose "**Properties**"
[image]

2)choose **java build Path** from the left side

[image]

3)Press on "**JRE System Library[JavaSe-1.5]**" and press on **Edit** button

4. in the open window we will **choose** the right JRE ( I use 11) and press *finish*

[image]

5)press **Apply** and **Apply and Close**

[image]

The issue suppose disappear

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you have Java >= 1.8 installed and is in use in your workspace, try confirming that you do not have 'Project Specific Settings' enabled for that particular project.